# Swift - Custom control for UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, custom-controls

I already created a custom control for UISlider. This UISlider have 2 thumbs so it can find minimum and maximum values. I take these tutorials as my references.

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift
2. http://www.sitepoint.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one/

Compiled successfully but my UISlider looks weird. You can take a look my github repository here.

https://github.com/datomnurdin/RevivalxSwiftSlider

My custom control for UISlider

```
import UIKit

class RangeSlider: UIControl {

    var minimumValue: Float!
    var maximumValue: Float!
    var minimumRange: Float!
    var selectedMinimumValue: Float!
    var selectedMaximumValue: Float!

    var distanceFromCenter: Float!

    var _padding: Float!

    var _maxThumbOn: Bool!
    var _minThumbOn: Bool!

    var _minThumb = UIImageView()
    var _maxThumb = UIImageView()
    var _track = UIImageView()
    var _trackBackground = UIImageView()

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        _minThumbOn = false;
        _maxThumbOn = false;
        _padding = 20;

        let _trackBackground = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bar-background.png"))
        _trackBackground.center = self.center;
        self.addSubview(_trackBackground)

        let _track = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bar-highlight.png"))
        _track.center = self.center
        self.addSubview(_track)


        let _minThumb = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "handle.png"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "handle-hover.png"))
        _minThumb.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.frame.size.height,self.frame.size.height);
        _minThumb.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        self.addSubview(_minThumb)

        let _maxThumb = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "handle.png"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "handle-hover.png"))
        _maxThumb.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.frame.size.height,self.frame.size.height)
        _maxThumb.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        self.addSubview(_maxThumb)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {


        _minThumb.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(self.xForValue(selectedMinimumValue)), self.center.y);

        _maxThumb.center = CGPointMake(CGFloat(self.xForValue(selectedMaximumValue)), self.center.y)

        NSLog("Tapable size %f", _minThumb.bounds.size.width);
        self.updateTrackHighlight()

    }

    func xForValue(value: Float) -> Float {
        return (Float(self.frame.size.width) - (_padding * 2)) * ((value - minimumValue) / (maximumValue - minimumValue)) + _padding
    }

    func valueForX(x: Float) -> Float {
        return minimumValue + (x - _padding) / (Float(self.frame.size.width) - (_padding * 2)) * (maximumValue - minimumValue)
    }

    func continueTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        if !_minThumbOn && !_maxThumbOn {
            return true
        }

        var touchPoint: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self)


        if (_minThumbOn != nil) {
            _minThumb.center = CGPointMake(max(CGFloat(self.xForValue(minimumValue)),min(touchPoint.x - CGFloat(distanceFromCenter), CGFloat(self.xForValue(selectedMaximumValue - minimumRange)))),CGFloat(_minThumb.center.y))
            selectedMinimumValue = self.valueForX(Float(_minThumb.center.x))
        }

        if (_maxThumbOn != nil) {
            _maxThumb.center = CGPointMake(min(CGFloat(self.xForValue(maximumValue)), max(touchPoint.x - CGFloat(distanceFromCenter), CGFloat(self.xForValue(selectedMinimumValue + minimumRange)))), CGFloat(_maxThumb.center.y))
            selectedMaximumValue = self.valueForX(Float(_maxThumb.center.x))
        }

        self.updateTrackHighlight()
        self.setNeedsLayout()

        self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        return true
    }

    func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        var touchPoint: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self)

        if(CGRectContainsPoint(_minThumb.frame, touchPoint)){
            _minThumbOn = true;
            distanceFromCenter = Float(touchPoint.x - _minThumb.center.x)
        }
        else if(CGRectContainsPoint(_maxThumb.frame, touchPoint)){
            _maxThumbOn = true;
            distanceFromCenter = Float(touchPoint.x - _maxThumb.center.x)

        }
        return true;


    }

    func endTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, event: UIEvent) {
        _minThumbOn = false;
        _maxThumbOn = false;
    }

    func updateTrackHighlight() {
        _track.frame = CGRectMake(
        _minThumb.center.x,
        _track.center.y - (_track.frame.size.height/2),
        _maxThumb.center.x - _minThumb.center.x,
        _track.frame.size.height
        );
    }


}
```

My output

[image]

It suppose to be like this

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: i think may problem of the Image try to focus over it may be solve your problem using image width change

Comment: For verification you just change the background of UIImageView so you can get the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies at the 'let'.

```
_minThumb = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "handle.png"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "handle-hover.png"))
    _minThumb.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.frame.size.height,self.frame.size.height);
    _minThumb.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    self.addSubview(_minThumb)

     _maxThumb = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "handle.png"), highlightedImage: UIImage(named: "handle-hover.png"))
    _maxThumb.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, self.frame.size.height,self.frame.size.height)
    _maxThumb.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    self.addSubview(_maxThumb)
```

Just remove the 'let' and it should work, this is because you are using _minThumb and _maxThumb globally, but you declared both as a constant, so they would not respond to any changes once initalized.

Comment: my both thumbs already show up, but can't  slide it. do you know why?